# How to improve readability of a big lisp function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

My main method (`remove-random-edge`) looks quite difficult to read. I'm new to list, so would appreciate *any* advice on how to improve the code.

```
(defun find-node (node graph)
  (find-if #'(lambda (i) (eql node (first i))) graph))

;; Input, graph, is in form ((from-1 to-1 to-2 to-3 ...)
;;                           (from-2 to-4 to-5 to-6 ...) ...)
;; where from-n and to-n are integers.
(defun remove-random-edge (graph)
  "Remove one random edge from a graph given as adjacency list."
  (let* ((node-list-1 (elt graph (random (length graph))))
         (node-1 (first node-list-1))
         (destinations (remove-duplicates (rest node-list-1)))
         (node-2 (elt destinations (random (length destinations))))
         (node-list-2 (find-node node-2 graph)))
    (flet ((replace-tail-for-head (node) (if (eql node node-2) node-1 node))
           (is-head-p (node) (eql node-1 node))
           (is-tail-p (node) (eql node-2 node))
           (starts-with-tail-p (nodes) (eql node-2 (first nodes))))
      (setf (rest node-list-1) (concatenate 'list 
                                 (rest node-list-1)
                                 (remove-if #'is-head-p (rest node-list-2)))) 
      (loop for node in (remove-duplicates (rest node-list-2))
            with match
            with repcd 
            do (setf match (find-node node graph))
            do (setf repcd (if (eql node node-1)
                             (remove-if #'is-tail-p (rest match))
                             (map 'list #'replace-tail-for-head (rest match))))
            do (setf (rest match) (sort repcd #'<))) 
      (remove-if #'starts-with-tail-p graph))))
```

*UPD*: With review comments applied:

```
(defun remove-random-edge (graph)
  "Remove one random edge from a graph given as adjacency list."
  (let* ((head-list (elt graph (random (length graph))))
         (head (first head-list))
         (destinations (remove-duplicates (rest head-list)))
         (tail (elt destinations (random (length destinations))))
         (tail-list (assoc tail graph)))
    (flet ((replace-tail-for-head (node) (if (eql node tail) head node)))
      (setf (rest head-list) (concatenate 'list 
                               (rest head-list)
                               (remove head (rest tail-list)))) 
      (loop for node in (remove-duplicates (rest tail-list))
            for match = (assoc node graph)
            do (setf (rest match) (if (eql node head)
                                    (remove tail (rest match))
                                    (mapcar #'replace-tail-for-head (rest match)))))
      (remove tail graph :key #'first))))
```

Before:

```
15.109 seconds of real time
50,245,719,578 processor cycles
767,039,256 bytes consed
```

After:

```
2.312 seconds of real time
7,665,669,728 processor cycles
778,172,816 bytes consed
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Superficial

Your `find-node` is actually (almost) [`assoc`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_assocc.htm) or, if you prefer, `(find node graph :key #'first)`.

Use [`mapcar`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) instead of `map 'list` because it makes the intent clearer (the difference is that `mapcar` takes only lists and `map` any sequence).

You need just one `do` in `loop`; you can even fold all your `setf`s into one `(setf a b c d e f)`.

In `loop`, `with` should (stylistically) come before `for`.

### Deep

Your code looks too complicated for what it does.

None of your `flet` local functions is really necessary.
E.g., `(remove-if #'is-head-p ...)` should be `(remove node-1 ...)`, 
and `(remove-if #'starts-with-tail-p ...)` should be `(remove node-2 ... :key #'first)`;
this would make the code both faster and cleaner.

Your `loop` should be

```
(loop for node in (remove-duplicates (rest node-list-2))
      for match = (find-node node graph)
      for repcd = (if (eql node node-1)
                      (remove-if #'is-tail-p (rest match))
                      (map 'list #'replace-tail-for-head (rest match))))
      do (setf (rest match) (sort repcd #'<)))
```

### General

Usually it is better to use the most specific function you need. E.g., use `setq` on simple variables (instead of `setf` which also supports general references). Use `mapcar` instead of `map 'list` when working with lists (as opposed to vectors).

Comment: Thank you, very informative. I missed the fact that `setf` can be folded, and the fact that `flet` is redundant is totally clear now, after you pointed that out. Why is `mapcar` preferable over `map` here, also, is `with` before `for` a stylistic preference?

Comment: @zzandy: `with` before `for` is stylistic. `mapcar` make your intent clearer. See edits